# How to convert string into a date time format in R

Tags: r, date, powerbi

I have a string in the form:

> dd/mm/yyyy 10:00:00 PM

How do I convert this into a date in R?

Currently, I'm using R to create a visual I need that PowerBI can't do but I know R will do it. However R wont recognize my timestamp as a date even though in PowerBI it is set to be a date.

Comment: If any answer does what you want, please consider ticking it as correct. A reputation of 1 is enough to do it. I remind you this because newcomers often forget to do so. See [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) That being said, welcome on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/).

Answer (score 0):

The lubridate package can help. Try

```
library lubridate
dmy_hms('10/11/1985 10:00:00 PM') # some random date. dmy is for day month year
class(dmy_hms('10/11/1985 10:00:00 PM')) # this is a date
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach using only the R-builtin [Base Package](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/base-package.html).

Say you have

```
> d_as_str <- '01/12/1986 10:00:00 PM'
```

You could do

```
> d_as_obj <- base::strptime(d_as_str, format='%d/%m/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')
> format(d_as_obj, "%H:%M:%S")
[1] "22:00:00"
> format(d_as_obj, "%d/%m/%Y %H:%M:%S")
[1] "01/12/1986 22:00:00"
```